# Can't read properly with fscanf

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, scanf

I have the following difficulties. I'm trying to read this file.

```
3
1 2 3
2
4 5
```

The numbers that are alone are the size of the array `(3 and 2)`. And the following numbers are the array.
So `3 is the size of (1,2,3)` and `2 is the size of (4,5)`.

I wrote a code on C to read that numbers and store them in arrays that use `malloc()`.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
main(){
    int i=0, j, *size, *vector;

    size=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    vector=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("file.dat", "rt");

    if (file==NULL){
        printf("Exit ...");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        do{
            fscanf(file,"%d",&size[i]);
            for(j=0;j<=size[i];j++){
                fscanf(file,"%d",&vector[j]);
            }
            i++;

        }while(feof(file)==0);
    }
    fclose(file);

return 0;
}
```

Is reading the file properly but if I printf the numbers I get:

```
3
5
2
3
4
2
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 1):

Two things to mention here.

1. You have allocated memory for only one variable through `malloc()`, but you try to access beyond the allocated memory in the `do...while` loop. You need to `realloc()`, as and when required.
2. Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Comment: I can only use `malloc()`.

Comment: @Vladimir then the whole purpose of malloc would be lost, probably. If you know and allocate the required amount of memory beforehand, why to use dynamic allocation, at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int i, j, size, *size_v, **vector;

    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("file.dat", "rt");

    if (file==NULL){
        printf("Exit ...");
        exit(1);
    }

    i = 0;//scan file
    while(EOF != fscanf(file, "%d", &size)){
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
            fscanf(file, "%*d");
        }
        i++;
    }
    rewind(file);

    size_v = malloc(i * sizeof(int));
    vector = malloc(i * sizeof(int*));

    i = 0;//read file
    while(EOF != fscanf(file, "%d", &size_v[i])){
        vector[i] = malloc(size_v[i] * sizeof(int));

        for(j = 0; j < size_v[i]; j++){
            fscanf(file, "%d", &vector[i][j]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    //print & deallocate
    size = i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        printf("%d\n", size_v[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < size_v[i]; ++j){
            printf("%d ", vector[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(vector[i]);
    }
    free(vector);
    free(size_v);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int i, j, size, *vector;

    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("file.dat", "rt");

    if (file==NULL){
        printf("Exit ...");
        exit(1);
    }

    i = 0;
    while(EOF != fscanf(file, "%d", &size)){
        printf("%d\n", size);//each loop
        vector = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
            fscanf(file, "%d", &vector[j]);
        }
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
            printf("%d ", vector[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(vector);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int i, j, k, size, size_sum, *size_v, *vector;

    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("file.dat", "rt");

    if (file==NULL){
        printf("Exit ...");
        exit(1);
    }

    i = 0;//scan file
    size_sum = 0;
    while(EOF != fscanf(file, "%d", &size)){
        size_sum += size;
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
            fscanf(file, "%*d");
        }
        i++;
    }
    rewind(file);

    size_v = malloc(i * sizeof(int));
    vector = malloc(size_sum * sizeof(int));

    i = 0;//read file
    k = 0;
    while(EOF != fscanf(file, "%d", &size_v[i])){
        for(j = 0; j < size_v[i]; j++){
            fscanf(file, "%d", &vector[k++]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    //print & deallocate
    size = i;
    size_sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        printf("%d\n", size_v[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < size_v[i]; ++j){
            printf("%d ", vector[j + size_sum]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        size_sum += size_v[i];
    }
    free(vector);
    free(size_v);

    return 0;
}
```